# Calculating probability of a Gaussian random variable

Tags: probability, integration

Let $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$. I am trying to show that, $P(|X - \mu| \leq 0.675 \sigma) = \frac{1}{2}$. I know that,

\begin{align*}
P(|X - \mu| \leq \alpha \sigma) &= \Phi(\mu + \alpha \sigma) - \Phi(\mu - \alpha \sigma) \\
&= \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2 \pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\mu + \alpha \sigma} e^{-(x - \mu)^2/2\sigma^2} dx - \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2 \pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\mu - \alpha \sigma} e^{-(x - \mu)^2/2\sigma^2} dx \\
&= \frac{\alpha \sigma}{\sigma \sqrt{2 \pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{1} e^{-((\alpha \sigma x +\mu) - \mu)^2/2\sigma^2} dx - \frac{\alpha \sigma}{\sigma \sqrt{2 \pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{-1} e^{-((\alpha \sigma x +\mu) - \mu)^2/2\sigma^2} dx \\
&= \frac{\alpha \sigma}{\sigma \sqrt{2 \pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{1} e^{-(\alpha x)^2/2} dx - \frac{\alpha \sigma}{\sigma \sqrt{2 \pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{-1} e^{-(\alpha x)^2/2} dx \\
&= \frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}\int_{-1}^{1} e^{-(\alpha x)^2/2} dx \\
\end{align*}

I am trying to show that when $\alpha = 0.675$, $P(|X - \mu| < 0.675\sigma) = \frac{1}{2}$. Is my work above correct? According to wolfram-alpha, $\frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}\int_{-1}^{1} e^{-(\alpha x)^2/2} \approx \frac{1}{2}$ when $\alpha = 0.675$, but is there any way to do this without numerical integration?

Comment: I do not think you know that.  If $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ then $P(|X - \mu| \leq \alpha \sigma) = \Phi( \alpha ) - \Phi( - \alpha) = 2\Phi( \alpha ) -1$ when $\alpha \ge 0$ and that is about as far as you can go.

Comment: It is true that when $P(\alpha)=\frac34$ and so $P(|X - \mu| \leq \alpha \sigma) = 2\Phi( \alpha ) -1 =\frac12$ then $\alpha \approx 0.67448975$, but that requires numerical methods

Comment: @Henry I made a mistake in my work and forgot to scale the value of the integral when I rescaled the interval. It works out now, but I can't figure out how to do this non-numerically.

Comment: That is because it cannot really be done non-numerically. We have statistical tables and their computer equivalents for exactly that reason